# How can I see the return type function in PhpStorm when the cursor moves on that function?

Tags: phpstorm

Visual Studio Code:

[image]

When I'm using Visual Studio Code and my cursor moves over a property, an small tooltip box shows the return type of that property.

How can I see this kind of tooltip in PhpStorm?

Comment: Is it possible to see this in PhpStorm?

Answer (score 3):

To have quick detailed info -- invoke `View | Quick Documentation` (<kbd>Ctrl + Q</kbd> on Windows using Default keymap) while having caret placed on the desired symbol (class/function/variable/etc).

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/inline-documentation.html#d427447e209

---

To have brief tooltip -- just hover over function with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key pressed.

---

To have "Quick Documentation" window appearing automatically (without the need to invoke it manually) -- enable corresponding configuration option:

`Settings/Preferences | Editor | General --> Show quick documentation on mouse move`

NOTE: because that popup is quite large ... it's not super practical to have it popping up automatically like that as it will cover quite a bit of screen space -- may cover few next/previous lines of code that you may be interesting to see at the same time.